# How to get result with square bracket surrounded to each value when using IN keyword in Pivot table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am writing the sql query for creating the pivot table. I have the sample code where I am getting the result without error but the result should be values surrounded by square bracket to each value instead to the whole result. How do I setup for it?

I have tried using quote function but it is putting square bracket around the whole output.

```
DECLARE @CityNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', @t varchar(max) = 'jay, sam'

SELECT  @CityNames +=   QUOTENAME(@t)+ ','


select @CityNames
```

I expect the output to be [jay],[sam], but the actual output is [jay,sam].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select '[' + @t + replace(@t, ', ', '], [') + ']')
```

`QUOTENAME()` treats the string as a single identifier, quoting appropriately  The above should work for most reasonable column names.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is correct and I found the answer using quotename function.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer by using QUOTENAME() function, we can follow the below code or above code by @gordon Linoff.

```
 DECLARE @CityNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', @t nvarchar(max) = 'jay, sam', @result 
 varchar(max),  @sSQL nvarchar(max)

SELECT  @CityNames +=    + QUOTENAME(value)+','  from (select value from 
 dbo.fx_split( @t, ','))x


IF (RIGHT(@CityNames, 1) = ',')
   set @CityNames = LEFT(@CityNames, LEN(@CityNames) - 1)

   select @citynames
```